# Custom Product Search URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Hi I have tried the following code and does seem to work and changes the regular search url for a keyword "holi"

https://www.englishbix.com/search/?s=holi&post_type=product to https://www.englishbix.com/search/holi/

but it uses the default search template to display the product search results instead of the woocommerce search result template.

```
//change the url to static slug instead of dynamic one
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

[Results I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgHNh.png)

[Results I get with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKZi.png)